# How does conan handle universal builds on MacOS

Tags: macos, apple-m1, conan

I am googling but unable to find some definitive answer.
How does conan handle universal builds for x86 and arm64 on MacOS?

We are developping an application and use conan to build a depednency for our project. Then we redistribute that with the application.

I would like to try to build that on MacOS with M1 processor. How to be sure that conan builds "universal" - fat -binaries?

Can you point me to documentation? Explain? I am not sure how it exactly works.

Comment: Conan package binaries are intended to be single-config, containing 1 binary for 1 configuration. For distributing outside of Conan universal builds, there could be several mechanisms. For example, [deployers] (https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/extensions/deployers.html) can be used to gather binaries from Conan packages which can be used to create the final fat binaries to distribute outside of Conan